# How can I add row or col in the left of the matrix?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matrix, push-back

I know how to add row or col in the right of the matrix:

```
cv::Mat row = cv::Mat::ones(1, 3, CV_64F);  // 3 cols, 1 row
m.push_back(row);                           // 3 cols, 5 rows
```

But I don't know how to add row or col in the left of the matrix.

I'm trying to make a map from a video. So is there any effective solution?

Comment: You can look for `cv::hconcat()` and `cv::vconcat()`

Comment: but should I rotate the matris and then use cv::hconcat() or cv::vconcat() ?

Comment: Completely depends upon your use case, as what type of matrices you want to concatenate?

Comment: I am studying on pictures from a video. also can you look this probem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093644/copyto-and-range-problem-while-making-big-image-from-frames